# How to launch process from android app with ROOT permissions

Tags: android, process, permissions, root

How to launch a process from android app with ROOT permissions?

I've found similar questions but they are not working for me: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757589/android-su-permissions-ioexception), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753988/running-an-app-with-root-permission-in-android)

Error log (**IOException** when using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);`):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su -c, /data/data/%my_app_package%/%app% %params%] Working Directory: null Environment: null
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:123)
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): ... 5 more
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
08-22 11:02:17.515: WARN/System.err(19804): ... 8 more
```

Similar error output when launching using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
08-22 11:19:34.052: WARN/System.err(22054): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su -c, /data/data/%app_package%/%app% %parameters%] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=9, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/sdcard0, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework_ext.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar, ANDROID_DATA=/data, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=8,65536]
08-22 11:19:34.052: WARN/System.err(22054): at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
08-22 11:19:34.052: WARN/System.err(22054): at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:195)
08-22 11:19:34.052: WARN/System.err(22054): ... 5 more
08-22 11:19:34.052: WARN/System.err(22054): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

I'm absolutely sure the device is rooted and it works okay. Sometimes i'm asked for granting root permissions to the apps. In this case i'm not asked, just getting error.

How to ask root permission for the app in runtime? Does it grant root permissions for all started processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference on how to build command-line for process for `ProcessBuilder`:

**NOT** working code:

- `commandLine.add("su -c"); commandLine.add("app"); commandLine.add("params")`
- `commandLine.add("sudo"); commandLine.add("app"); commandLine.add("params")`

**WORKING** code:

- `commandDownloader.add("su"); commandDownloader.add("-c"); commandLine.add("app");`

For working code i'm asked for permission by Android OS (MIUI in my case to be more detailed)